# Js - Временная остановка цикла For

Tags: javascript

Есть цикл, который при каждой создаёт кнопку. При нажатии на кнопку вызывается таймер на определённое время, выбранное пользователем. Надо чтобы до нажатия кнопки и окончания таймера цикл временно прекращал работу.
Для наглядности, вот упрощённая версия кода:

```
function startExercise() {
    for(let i = 0; i < ec; i++) {
        for(let j = 0; j < storage.getItem('ic' + i); j++) {

            let nBtn = document.createElement('button');
            nBtn.className = 'exercise-btn';
            nBtn.onclick = function() { startTimer(storage.getItem('tm0')) };

            document.getElementById('container').appendChild(nBtn);

        }
    }
}

function startTimer(time) {

    let nTime = document.createElement('p');
    nTime.className = 'timer';
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(nTime);

    let sec = 0;
    let min = time;
    function updateTimer() {
        if(sec < 0) {
            sec = 59;
            min--;
        }

        nTime.innerHTML = min + ':' + (sec < 10 ? '0' : '') + sec;

        setTimeout(updateTimer, 1000, --sec);
    }

    updateTimer(time);
}
```

Comment: Нужно останавливать цикал — не запускайте цикл ) Функция, останавливающая таймер, сама может выполнить код для "следующей итерации".

Comment: А по приличнее никак не придумать тестирующую систему с обратным отсчетом?

Comment: Все приходят со своим мышлением и придумывают велосипед